# UITabBarController and Left Sliding Menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, slidingmenu

I have a tabBarController in my iOS project, which is on top of every screen.

I am trying to implement a left sliding menu to it using the [PKRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController). The problem that I am facing is that the sliding menu only works (shows) when I set the tabBarController to hidden or remove from super view. Which in return hides the tab bar on the bottom, which is what I don't want.

So, I was wondering if someone could give me some pointers on how to fix this.

Comment: As a general UI pattern, a hidden side menu area like that replaces a tab bar interface. But, with a quick look at that library, it seems like the tabBarController you have should be set to the "front" controller: `[PKRevealController revealControllerWithFrontViewController:tabBarController leftViewController:someotherthing options:options];` Is it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This didn't quite work. When I tried what you suggested, it moves the whole screen "up" and with the remaining space on the bottom, I can swipe left and right on that little space.

Here is a link to what it looks like. The titles on top is the tab bar and then the gray area on the bottom is the area I can use to swipe left and right.

http://i.imgur.com/VnqoDNu.png

Comment: Also, it doesn't actually change the front screen. It changes the screen in the background but not in the front. You can tell that the back screen changes because the little area on the bottom changes.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?